# flink gelly implementing closeness

Tags: apache-flink, gelly

I aim in implementing closeness centrality in *Flink Gelly* and trying to use a map function on each node for calculating SSSP for it. 
Graph is not serialized and, so, I can't send it to each node. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.